# RabbitMQ keep messages in queue

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, race-condition, bunny

I am streaming a tty's stdout and stderr to RabbitMQ (logs to be exact). These logs can be viewed on a website and while the content is streamed to RabbitMQ they are consumed by the webserver and forwarded to the client using WebSockets. Logs are immediately persisted after sending it to RabbitMQ.

When the user accesses the website the persisted logs are rendered and the consecutive parts are streamed using WebSockets. The problem is that there is a race condition as the persisted logs might be missing chunks of the log that occurred between rendering the site and receiving the first chunk via WebSocket.

My idea was to keep all chunks in the queue and send those via the WebSocket after connecting. Additionally I would add a worker to listen to some kind of a "finished" event which then takes everything in the queue and persists it at once.

The problem is that I don't know if this is possible using RabbitMQ or how. Any ideas or other solutions?

I don't think it really matters but my stack is using Ruby Sinatra and the Bunny RabbitMQ client.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with your general idea about picking up where you left off, after loading the intial page, what you're trying to do isn't something that should be done from RabbitMQ.

There are a lot of potential problems that this would cause, which I've [outlined in a blog post, previously](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/).

Instead of trying to do this w/ RMQ, I would do this from a database layer.

As you push things into the database, you have an ID - hopefully one that is sequential. If not, add a sequence to the entries.

When you load the page for the user, send the current ID that they are at down to the browser.

After the page finishes loading and you're setting up the websocket connection, send the user's current spot in the list of messages via the websocket. then the websocket connection can use that id to say "give me all the messages after this id, and start streaming them"

Again, this is not done via RabbitMQ (see [my article on why this is a bad idea](http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/21/how-to-do-user-notifications-from-rabbitmq-messages/)), but via your database and sequential IDs.